# What is the difference between su - oracle and pbrun /bin/su - oracle

Tags: linux, oracle-linux, oracle-database

Could anyone explain the difference between the below commands:

```
su - oracle
```

and

```
pbrun /bin/su - oracle
```

Answer (score 0):

The pbrun command is used to request that an application or command be run in a controlled account. I believe the su creds can also be used at the same time. It also has several debugging options. See:

http://linux-n-unix.blogspot.com/2010/07/what-is-pbrun-command.html